# What all options do I have to build a RESTful web service?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

We have a requirement to build a RESTful web service. I've been reading up some articles to understand what are the various options(PL, frameworks, etc) that I could use.

The most obvious option seems to be using Spring with Jersey. What could be the other alternatives and how would it better/worse that Spring with Jersey.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what you usually work with. If you use Spring, find something which works well with it (probably jersey). But this question has tons of possible answers the way you state it.

Comment: @XtremeBiker My objective is to understand the various options and choose what's best. I know this may boil down to one's choice and preference. But a universal voice could help making a decision.

Comment: I agree, that's an interesting topic to debate. However, this type of questions don't fit Stack Overflow, because it's a site focused on concrete answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Playframework (Aysync, scalable, different plugins support like security, ddatabase, caching,...)
2. Dropwizard - simple but powerful it also supports different plugins.